# How do I mark ids that have had occurrences in the past X days? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

If I have table like so:

```
 ID  |  Date  
 1   |  2018-01-01  
 1   |  2018-01-10  
 1   |  2018-02-02
```

How do I get a marker of say "past 10 days" by CASE'ing to get the following:

```
 ID  |  Date        | Marker  
 1   |  2018-01-01  | 0  
 1   |  2018-01-10  | 1  
 1   |  2018-02-02  | 0
```

I need a solution which checks the row id, looks at its date, looks at all previous dates for that id and marks whether the current id has *been* within reach of "past x days".

I have this nailed in DAX with EARLIER(), however whatever I try in SQL Server (be it LAG, WHERE, OVER() and etc.) doesn't seem to work. I wish I could tell SQL: "WHERE earlier date + x >= date".

Please help me understand SQL's quirks.

P.S. looking for a solution without additonal joins - my table is large enough as it is.

EDIT MAY 24th 2018:

I do not want to just compare the last X days from GetDate(), because what I mean with Last X Days is for that Specific ID in the row, to check for instances with a date that is in the past x days with the same ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to see if the date is exactly 10 days from the previous, per ID. Change to <= if you want it for the "range"

```
select
   id
   ,date
   ,Marker = case when dateadd(day,-10,[Date]) = lag([Date]) over (partition by id order by [Date]) then 1 else 0 end 
from YourTable
order by id, [Date]
```

Comment: One oddity here: suppose that the source data includes two records that have the same `ID` and the same `Date`, and there exists no record with that `ID` that falls within the preceding ten days. Your query will set `Marker = 0` for one of those two records and `Marker = 1` for the other. It's not clear to me whether the OP wants 0 or 1 in such a case, but surely both records should return the same result.

Comment: I'm almost certain the data shown is incomplete @JoeFarrell and if it's not, I can't see how it's useful so I ignored this assumption in the answer.

Comment: https://youtu.be/9bjQESZS8w0?t=80 I have to equate my situation to this.
And your solution to this: https://youtu.be/9bjQESZS8w0?t=146
And my reaction to this: https://youtu.be/9bjQESZS8w0?t=167

Good, work big fella (Scsimon)!

Comment: All joking aside, this is a very humbling experience, because I did not think to use lag with that kind of comparison (I needed a range, btw). This solution is very type-efficient, clear, understandable and works lightning fast.

You are a G(r)eek God.

Comment: But I do think making the marshmallow is harder haha.

Comment: Those moments really cracked me up in writing that comment. :D
I now am more confident in trying out every type of query combo where possible thanks to you. Just goes to show that CASE always kicks ass in any situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select *,
Case When DateDiff(d,LAG([Date]) OVER(Partition by ID order by [Date]),[Date]) <10 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS Marker
from myTable
```

Comment: This solution is tied with the best answer and in terms of speed is 1:1, and it's even more type-efficient. So good job, Sahi. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` to check for the existence of a record with the same ID within the past 10 days.

```
declare @SampleData table (ID bigint, [Date] date);
insert @SampleData values (1, '20180101'), (1, '20180110'), (1, '20180202');

select
    This.ID,
    This.[Date],
    Marker = convert(bit, case when exists 
    (
        select 1 
        from @SampleData Previous 
        where
            Previous.ID = This.ID and
            Previous.[Date] >= dateadd(day, -10, This.[Date]) and 
            Previous.[Date] < This.[Date]
    ) then 1 else 0 end)
from
    @SampleData This;
```

I know you said you didn't want any joins, and `EXISTS` technically is a join—called a semi-join—but the execution plan for this query is quite simple. I'd be curious to know how it performs against your table vs. a `LAG()`-based solution like scsimon's answer.

Comment: I marked scsimon's as a very humbling and concise solution, which also follows the no join rule. Fortunately, what you pointed out as the oddity below his post - is not a huge issue for me.
I will however try it out right now (I've tried out scsimon's) and compare it for you to test performance. :)

Comment: I am still on this query and I can tell you that performance-wise - this one is a nightmare. Scsimon's and Sahi's solutions are both <45 seconds to complete while this one is 1 hour in and shows no signs of stopping. Looks clear on what it will do, does it but boy does it take its time. Would not recommend this on a large set.

Comment: It ended up timed out after about 2,8 hours. :D Yeah, really not a game-changer, though the logic of the query is solid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

`select Id, Date, IIF(DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) < date, 1, 0) as marker from table_name`

Comment: This would help if GetDate() were the thing to check the date with. In this case - it will not, because I need a check with each row id's dates.